defer or delay script loading of calendly being loaded in elementor popup
I am loading a calendly CTA as iframe src on an elementor pro popup . It loads huge number of scripts and slows down the site during  TTFB & LCP etc. I was wondering how else can it be loaded as a popup so that the scripts are called only when someone clicks on the button and not preloaded.
the iframe script is simple
I tried using plugins to defer and delay all JS scripts and merge them together but the frame scripts dont get deferred I guess.
